# Is there a way to mention my bot in the Bot Framework Emulator?

Tags: javascript, botframework

I already know my bot's name: "Bot".

For debugging purposes, I decided to use the `eval()` function to read code from a file called "onMessage.js" for the `onMessage` function in my ActivityHandler:

```
const {TurnContext} = require('botbuilder');

var mentions = TurnContext.getMentions(context.activity);

console.log(`${mentions.length} mention(s) found:`);

for (var i = 0; i < mentions.length; i++) {
    console.log(mentions[i].mentioned);
}
```

This is so I do not have to wait and restart Restify every time I make a change to my code.

After the eval, `await next();` is called.

As for whenever I try to message my bot "Hello @Bot !", I get no mentions:

```
0 mention(s) found:
```

Does the emulator not support mentions? Is there a special trick to format my message so a certain part of it becomes a mention? I know that all I need to do in Discord is to have the `@` symbol followed by the username to create a mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator does not support/implement @mentions. Mentions are just part of a text message activity. Each channel (MS Teams, Slack, emulator, etc) handles them differently, and the formatting of the text is important in that aspect. For example, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/f164ffca2d580f5c8c0d96afc8075445e3e263c1/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs#L182) you can see that MS Teams needs `<at> </at>` surrounding the text to mention.

If Discord is your end goal, I think you need to look into more of how it implements mentions and then get your bot to format that in the correct way. You can also get a debug bot connected and then [debug through Ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/). My *assumption* is that you just need to get the correct formatting of the mention.